# Eleminating base_url() in every view for CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, base-url, relative-url

I am using CodeIgniter for my web app and i want to avoid on keep using base_url() function in all my urls in the views.

Now this code is what i want :

```
<a href="/user/create">Click me to create user</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>user/create">Click me to create user</a>
```

However, specifying "/user/create" will redirect me to below url which is incorrect

```
http://localhost/user/create
```

What i want is that "/user/create" url in href should automatically redirect me to

```
 http://localhost/myapp/user/create
```

without specifying base_url()

Is this possible?

This is my current .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# If your website begins from a folder e.g localhost/my_project then 
# you have to change it to: RewriteBase /my_project/
# If your site begins from the root e.g. example.local/ then
# let it as it is
RewriteBase /myapp/

# Protect application and system files from being viewed when the index.php is missing
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)

# Rewrite to index.php/access_denied/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]

# Allow these directories and files to be displayed directly:
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images)

# No rewriting
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]

# Rewrite to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use form helper library

//Controller

```
function __construct()
{
    parent:: __construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
}
```

//View

```
<?php echo anchor('user/create','Click me to create user');?>

This will create similar result as

<a href="/user/create">Click me to create user</a>
```

They are way much better than using base_url() for links.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I dont want to use any of the functions for the url i.e base_url(), site_url(), anchor(). I just want to avoid that since i dont want to always call that function in every url. Specifying like "/user/create" will be easier and faster for me and for the urls i will put in my views

Comment: i think you should , what is the point of using Framework if you do not use libraries,helpers . Just my two cents.

Comment: hi Wayne, yes i understand that helpers are available but it is much faster to code if i eliminate using base_url(). if i have many links in one page (including local css and js), it would be time-consuming for me if i use use base_url() in all links thats why i am asking if what i want is possible

Comment: I sincerely believe that "echo anchor('user/create','Create') " is a lot better than "<a href=<?php echo base_url('user/create');?>> Create</a>

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks for your replies. But i think you are not getting my point here. My point is i dont want to use any of the functions for url i.e anchor() or base_url().. what i want is in my post where i dont need to specify url functions in CI.. just specify relative url and the page will understand

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
href="user/create"
Just remove the first slash (/) before user and try.

Comment: actually this is what i am using now. this will work in forms or other links inside html page but doesnt work in javascript i.e window.location.href = "user/create"

any idea how to let it work in javascript? my javascript files location are in CIProject/assets/js/jsfile.js